# Which programming language's Syntax is this (Swift or Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to port my game from Android (Java) to IOS. I am using the real time multiplayer service from google. They provide a sample application on their website.

Which programming language is this? Swift or Objective C? Code on [google developers](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/realtimeMultiplayer).

Short excerpt from the link:

```
- (void)room:(GPGRealTimeRoom *)room didChangeStatus:(GPGRealTimeRoomStatus)status {
if (status == GPGRealTimeRoomStatusDeleted) {
    NSLog(@"RoomStatusDeleted");
    [self.lobbyDelegate multiPlayerGameWasCanceled];
    _roomToTrack = nil;
} else if (status == GPGRealTimeRoomStatusConnecting) {
    NSLog(@"RoomStatusConnecting");
} else if (status == GPGRealTimeRoomStatusActive) {
    NSLog(@"RoomStatusActive! Game is ready to go");
    _roomToTrack = room;

    // We may have a view controller up on screen if we're using the
    // invite UI
    [self.lobbyDelegate readyToStartMultiPlayerGame];
} else if (status == GPGRealTimeRoomStatusAutoMatching) {
    NSLog(@"RoomStatusAutoMatching! Waiting for auto-matching to take place");
    _roomToTrack = room;
} else if (status == GPGRealTimeRoomStatusInviting) {
    NSLog(@"RoomStatusInviting! Waiting for invites to get accepted");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unknown room status %ld", status);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Objective-C it is! BTW, not a proper place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is Objective-C.**

In objective-c `[]` is used for message passing(method call).

In swift `.(dot)` syntax is used for message passing(method call).